# On Godaddy, cannot connect to server

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel, laravel-5.6

Can't connect to the database from the server.
Included the IP address of a server. but still showing an error.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=43.255.154.108
DB_PORT=
DB_DATABASE=tla
DB_USERNAME=tla
DB_PASSWORD=Tla@123
```

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'tla'@'ip-43-255-154-108.ip.secureserver.net'

Comment: can't clear config also. getting the same above-mentioned error.

Comment: tried by removing the \bootstrap\cache\config.php. but error gets repeated.